# Scrolling Very Jumpy On Smaller Devices

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, background-image, fixed

I know the whole `background-attachment: fixed` is very boring and has been asked multiple times - But I'm desperate for some help. I've been coding for three months and am designing something for a friend, that I'll eventually add to my portfolio. Link to website [lengtest.com](http://lengtest.com).

So I managed to find code to work around the no fixed on mobile thingy, but now it doesnt scroll without lagging. Can anyone help? Or should I design a new page. My desktop site is fine. Just mobiles and ipads which are playing up.

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url("lengcover2.jpg");
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background position:left top;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('#container').css('background-position', 'left ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: could you show us an working example?

Comment: You are using a jquery function kinda "heavy" to mobile devices handle it every single time you scroll, so it's normal are lagging. What do you want to accomplish exactly that needs javascript? For sure you can do it only with css... I just want to understand better what do you want to do

Comment: It is lagging probably because of the mobile browser firing the `scroll` event in such a rapid manner that the browser cannot keep up with the calculating. You might want to try to throttle the callback, e.g. by [using a plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

Comment: I have experienced similar issues with `$(window).scroll()`. Different browsers implement when they trigger the scroll event differently. Some trigger the `.scroll()` every pixel of scrolling, some only when the scrolling stops, some when it starts and stops, it really just depends on your browser. I think this question will have a much more complex answer than you'd think

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers can have a harder time rendering scroll actions due to differences on when the event is firing. Some mobile devices won't actually activate your scroll until the whole action is done and others may be trying to fire it consecutively and create a snappy, jarring type feel. One popular way to avoid this is to set any function/action you want on a scroll, within a timer.

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {`
        var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#container').css('background-position', 'left ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
    }, 100);
});
```

Here you can see that every time a scroll fires, a check for the timer is initiated. If the timer is already set to go off, it clears it. Then directly after, a new timer is set.

Note: I would recommend putting a transition call on at least your background-image call and possibly your background-position.